# how to write more than one joins in Big Query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, outer-join

I want to convert following Oracle query into equivalent Big Query SQL.

Below is old syntax of right join but same operator (+) is not available in Big Query.

```
SELECT * FROM 
t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10
WHERE 
    t1.CODE (+) = t2.CODE
AND t1.BRANCH_NBR (+) = t2.BRANCH_NBR
AND t1.NBR (+) = t2.NBR
AND t1.DT (+) = t2.DT

AND t3.COMPANY (+) = t4.CODE
AND t3.INV_PART_NBR (+) = t4.PART_NBR
AND t5.COMPANY (+) = t3.COMPANY
AND t5.CLIENT_NBR (+) = t3.CLIENT_NBR
AND t5.SEQ_NBR (+) = t3.SEQ_NBR
AND t6.COMPANY (+) = t3.COMPANY
AND t6.CLIENT_NBR (+) = t3.CLIENT_NBR
AND t6.SEQ_NBR (+) = t3.SEQ_NBR

AND t7.COMPANY (+) = t8.COMPANY
AND t7.CLIENT_NBR (+) = t8.MV_NUMBER
AND t7.VENDOR_CLASS (+) = 'A'
AND t9.COMPANY (+) = t2.CODE
AND t9.BR_NBR (+) = t2.BB_NBR
AND t9.CUST_NBR (+) = t2.BC_NBR
AND t9.SUFFIX (+) = t2.SHIP_TO_SFX
AND t10.COMPANY (+) = t2.CODE
AND t10.BR_NBR (+) = t2.BB_NBR
AND t10.CUST_NBR (+) = t2.BC_NBR
AND t10.SUFFIX (+) = '000'
```

I tried with right outer join but received errors.
this is sample join statements from actual code and not pasting all join

```
SELECT *
FROM
`t1` AS t1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN `t2` AS t2 USING (CODE,BRANCH_NBR,NMBR,DT),
`t3` AS t3
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 't4' AS t4 USING (CODE,PART_NBR,COMPANY)
```

**Error received**
*Syntax error: RIGHT JOIN must be parenthesized when following a comma join. Also, if the preceding comma join is a correlated CROSS JOIN that unnests an array, then CROSS JOIN syntax must be used in place of the comma join*

Comment:  hi! Can you please update your question with the right outer join you tried and the errors? Thanks!

Comment: @JasonRStevensCFA pls check error

Answer (score 0):

The `(+)` operator in oracle is an operator used for performing joins.

```
SELECT * FROM 
t1,t2
WHERE 
    t1.CODE (+) = t2.CODE
```

Now, an equivalent would be

```
SELECT * FROM 
t2 left join t1
on 
    t1.CODE = t2.CODE
```

Similarly, it will apply for all tables and once changed, your result should appear as expected.

Comment: have you try more than one join statements  ? and this is right outer join not left ..

Comment: Yes, it will work for any number of tables. Secondly, the answer I wrote just swapped tables making it a left join yet preserving the result. Ultimately in right join you are trying to keep all rows of other table and match rows from the first table. So, its one and the same.